# How to build a HATEOAS Link with a regex path variable from a super class in SPRING

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-hateoas, hateoas

The following code

```java
Link view = linkTo(methodOn(QuotesView.class).quote(quoteId, null)).withRel("selfView");
```

renders to:

```
http://localhost:8080/{urlLocale:[a-z](?:-[a-z])?}/quotes/1
```

How can I pass a value for 'urlLocale' to the builder and have it reflected in the link?

Answer (score 1):

You need to hand a method parameter that maps the `urlLocale` path variable.

Comment: urlLocale is a request scoped variable, set in a filter - it is not a method parameter